# Python Crash Course bizarre error related to Classes

Tags: python, class, compiler-errors

Like many, I'm trying to make my way through Eric Matthes', "Python Crash Course," and am transcribing his code verbatim using Sublime Text as my editor/IDE.

While trying to learn about Classes (chapter 9), trying to create an instance from the class Car, I get this error message:

TypeError: Car() takes no arguments (referring to line 26: my_new_car = Car('audi', 'a4', 2015).

I've posted the code below (with one difference: for the sake of simplicity, I put all the code into one file instead of importing Car).

```
class Car():

def _init_(self, make, model, year):
    self.make = make
    self.model = model
    self.year = year
    self.odometer_reading = 0

def get_descriptive_name(self):
    long_name = str(self.year) + " " +self.make + " " + self.model
    return long_name.title()

def read_odometer():
    print("This car has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " miles on it.")

def update_odometer(self, mileage):

    if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
        self.odometer_reading = mileage
    else:
        print("You can't roll back an odometer!")

def increment_odometer(self, miles):
    self.odometer_reading += miles

my_new_car = Car('audi', 'a4', 2015)
print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())

my_new_car.odometer_reading = 23
my_new_car.read_odometer()
```

I'd appreciate any help with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: `'_init_' != '__init__'`

Comment: Thank you so much.